# how to display a pop up in servlet page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to display a pop up window in servletpage.
Onclick of submit button on jsp page it is calling servlet page where I am trying to print result on pop up window.

I have used the bellow code which is not working.

```
out.println("<html><body onload=\"myFunction()\"><script>function myFunction() {alert("+splitVal[4]+");}</script></body></html>");
```

Comment: What means `not working`? Please provide the generated HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String val="any value";
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body onLoad=\"showResult();\">");
        out.println("<script>");
        out.println("function showResult(){");
        out.println("alert(\""+val+"\")");
        out.println("}");
        out.println("</script>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
```